# Why does my code cannot only pass test 4 in foo.bar Power-Hungry?

Tags: java, arrays, testing

## Power Hungry

Commander Lambda's space station is HUGE. And huge space stations take a LOT of power. Huge space stations with doomsday devices take even more power. To help meet the station's power needs, Commander Lambda has installed solar panels on the station's outer surface. But the station sits in the middle of a quasar quantum flux field, which wreaks havoc on the solar panels. You and your team of henchmen have been assigned to repair the solar panels, but you'd rather not take down all of the panels at once if you can help it, since they do help power the space station and all!

You need to figure out which sets of panels in any given array you can take offline to repair while still maintaining the maximum amount of power output per array, and to do THAT, you'll first need to figure out what the maximum output of each array actually is. Write a function solution(xs) that takes a list of integers representing the power output levels of each panel in an array, and returns the maximum product of some non-empty subset of those numbers. So for example, if an array contained panels with power output levels of ( 2, -3, 1, 0, -5 ), then the maximum product would be found by taking the subset: xs(0) = 2, xs(1) = -3, xs(4) = -5, giving the product 2*(-3)*(-5) = 30. So solution(2,-3,1,0,-5) will be "30".

Each array of solar panels contains at least 1 and no more than 50 panels, and each panel will have a power output level whose absolute value is no greater than 1000 (some panels are malfunctioning so badly that they're draining energy, but you know a trick with the panels' wave stabilizer that lets you combine two negative-output panels to produce the positive output of the multiple of their power values). The final products may be very large, so give the solution as a string representation of the number.

## Test cases

Your code should pass the following test cases.
Note that it may also be run against hidden test cases not shown here.

-- Python cases --
Input:
solution.solution(2, 0, 2, 2, 0)
Output:
8

Input:
solution.solution(-2, -3, 4, -5)
Output:
60

-- Java cases --
Input:
Solution.solution({2, 0, 2, 2, 0})
Output:
8

Input:
Solution.solution({-2, -3, 4, -5})
Output:
60

This is my code in Java with my tests that the code can pass with ease.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] array1 = {2, 0, 2, 2, 0}; // 8
        int[] array2 = {-2, -3, 4, -5}; // 60
        int[] array3 = {0}; // 0
        int[] array4 = {1};// 1
        int[] array5 = {0, 2, 2, -4, -2, -2};// 32
        int[] array6 = {1, 1, 2, 1, 1};// 2
        int[] array7 = {-3, 4, -5, -2};// 60
        int[] array8 = {0, -1};// 0
        int[] array9 = {0, 1};// 1
        int[] array10 = {4, 3, -5, -4, -5, -2, 0, 0, 1, 1, -2};// 2400

        System.out.println(solution(array1));
        System.out.println(solution(array2));
        System.out.println(solution(array3));
        System.out.println(solution(array4));
        System.out.println(solution(array5));
        System.out.println(solution(array6));
        System.out.println(solution(array7));
        System.out.println(solution(array8));
        System.out.println(solution(array9));
        System.out.println(solution(array10));
    }
```

```
    public static String solution(int[] xs) {
        int length = xs.length;
        int negativeCount = 0;
        int positiveCount = 0;
        int[] negativeArray = new int[length];
        int[] positiveArray = new int[length];
        long multiply = 1;

        if (length == 0) {
            return "0";
        }

        if (length == 1) {
            return String.valueOf(xs[0]);
        }

        for (int number : xs) {
            if (number < 0) {
                negativeArray[negativeCount] = number;
                negativeCount++;
            } else if (number > 0) {
                positiveArray[positiveCount] = number;
                positiveCount++;
            }
        }

        if ((positiveCount == 0 && negativeCount == 0) || (positiveCount == 0 && negativeCount == 1)) {
            return "0";
        }


        if (negativeCount % 2 == 1) {
            int largestNegativeNumber = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            int largestNegativeIndex = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < negativeArray.length; i++) {
                if (negativeArray[i] < 0 && negativeArray[i] > largestNegativeNumber) {
                    largestNegativeNumber = negativeArray[i];
                    largestNegativeIndex = i;
                }
            }
            if (largestNegativeIndex != -1) {
                int[] newArray = new int[negativeArray.length - 1];
                int j = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < negativeArray.length; i++) {
                    if (i != largestNegativeIndex) {
                        newArray[j++] = negativeArray[i];
                    }
                }

                negativeArray = newArray;
                negativeCount--;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < positiveCount + negativeCount; i++) {
            if (i < positiveCount) {
                multiply *= positiveArray[i];
            } else {
                multiply *= negativeArray[i - positiveCount];
            }
        }

        return Long.toString(multiply);
    }
```

I changed the code multiple times, of course, however now from all 5 test that foo.bar provides I cannot pass only the fourth one. I tried to look for more information, but I only found people that have done it in Python. When I look between my code in Java and the code of people, their code passes all tests in Python I do not see any method or logic that I have missed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a different approach. You must multiply all the array elements <> 0 and at the same time, find the biggest negative number. If the result is negative, divide it by the biggest negative number.
You have some issues in some corner cases, e.g. just a single negative number, or just a 0 and a negative number, or just zeros, then you must use a specific check for them.

```
    public String solution(int[] xs) {
        if (xs.length == 0) {
            return "-";
        }

        int multiplied = 0;
        Long result = 1L;
        int bigger = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int value : xs) {
            if (value != 0) {
                result = result * value;
                multiplied++;
                if (value < 0 && value > bigger) {
                    bigger = value;
                }
            }

        }
        if (multiplied == 0) {
            return "0";
        }

        if (result < 0) {
            if (xs.length > 1 & multiplied == 1) {
                return "0";
            }
            if (bigger == Integer.MIN_VALUE || xs.length == 1) {
                return "-";
            }
            result = result / bigger;
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSolution()
    {            
        Assert.assertEquals("8", solution(new int[] { 2, 0, 2, 2, 0 }));
        Assert.assertEquals("60", solution(new int[] { -2, -3, 4, -5 }));
        Assert.assertEquals("0", solution(new int[] { 0 }));
        Assert.assertEquals("1", solution(new int[] { 1 }));
        Assert.assertEquals("-", solution(new int[] { -1 }));
        Assert.assertEquals("-", solution(new int[] {}));
        Assert.assertEquals("0", solution(new int[] { 0, -1 }));
        Assert.assertEquals("0", solution(new int[] { 0, -1, 0, 0 }));
        Assert.assertEquals("0", solution(new int[] { 0, 0, 0 }));
        Assert.assertEquals("2", solution(new int[] { 2, 0 }));
        Assert.assertEquals("60", solution(new int[] { -3, 4, -5, -2 }));
        Assert.assertEquals("2400", solution(new int[] { 4, 3, -5, -4, -5, -2, 0, 0, 1, 1, -2 }));
    }
```